# ADODB.Command error 800a0e7a

Tags: iis, vbscript, asp-classic, odbc, ado

After running Windows Updates, my computer crashed resulting in repair of corrupted system files (not by me). Testing websites via localhost, my classic ASP/VBScript pages produced this error. After going through many similar articles for a week, I'm at a loss.
Running 64-bit Windows 7; Dreamweaver CS3 (32-bit); 32-bit ODBC and IIS 7.
Websites using classic ASP/VBScript with MS Access 2007 (Jet 4.0) and MySQL via ODBC connector.
Error when accessing System DSNs in ODBC thru DW only (no error via SysWOW64):
*You are logged on with non-Administrative privileges. System DSNs could not be created or modified.*
Other ODBC errors:
*Driver's ConfigDSN, ConfigDriver, or ConfigTranslator could not write to the registry*;
and
*Connection Failed [MySQL] [ODBC 5.3(w) driver] Can't connection to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)*
Notes:
All 32-bit ODBC user DSNs and drivers are listed.
IIS settings:
--Enable 32-bit Application: True
--Enable Parent Paths: True
--Managed Pipeline Mode: Classic
Permissions and full control set in IIS (default and specific websites), and folders and databases (including inetpub and WAMP), for all groups and users (except CREATOR OWNER).

Comment: try reinstalling ADO. Also you should probably add the system dsns by hand.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge, but since this is something I've never installed, how do I reinstall it? Where do I find it, is there a particular version to look for, and could reinstallation cause any unexpected problems or overwrite newer files?

Also, just to be sure, is the correct (default) IIS setting under Handler Mapping for ASPClassic executable file supposed to be %windir%\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll ?

Comment: Okay, I found these helpful articles: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675532.aspx, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/183606; and the download page at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937730.  I find this daunting.  I don't know which version to choose from.  Do I need the entire MDAC packet to repair ADO?  Can something go wrong?  Instead, would a Windows repair disc correct these issues by fixing the registry and/or reinstalling missing dll's?

Comment: Yes you need the entire MDAC package. Windows repair disk is not going to solve your problem.

Comment: Okay, thank you....should I download the latest version - MDAC 2.8 SP1 - for Windows 7 SP1? I assume security patches are included. Will I need the MDAC SDK for any reason? Also, I have a concern about the deprecated components listed at the bottom of this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810810.aspx.  I have always used MS Jet OLEDB 4.0 for my Access connections. Will that be preserved with my Office 2007 installation?

Comment: **It looks like my advice is out of date.** What version of Windows are you on? As per the article, MDAC ships with windows from Vista/Server 2008 onwards. And it looks like Jet OLEDB is a separate download. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734 Possibly that is all you need.

Comment: Pertinent system info is listed in my initial post - I'm on 64-bit Windows 7 Home Premium, SP1. Everything has worked for years until this recent crash was repaired. Now, database connections from classic ASP pages using MS Access driver, MySQL ODBC driver, and MS Jet.OLEDB.4.0 are broken.  Creating a new DW test site to test connection with a new DSN produced the same error.  Plus, the Connections folder that normally propagates in the new DW site folder when choosing a server model did not happen.

Comment: Now, Jet OLEDB is needed to connect to Jet. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734 Possibly that is all you need. Otherwise, sorry I haven't been able to help. You may have better luck on SuperUser.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not just the one connection that's broken, it's all of them, for ASP pages with recordsets from Access and MySQL. One more bit of discovery - when I run ODBC from SysWOW64, it allows me to open System DSNs and connections test fine. But when I run ODBC within DW, I receive errors on System DSNs and when testing connections. Seems to be disconnected communication between DW and ODBC. Odd, isn't it? Anyway, thanks for all your time on this.

Comment: That means that you are running 64bit iis worker not 32bit. You need 32 bit. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2007/11/03/iis7-running-32-bit-and-64-bit-asp-net-versions-at-the-same-time-on-different-worker-processes.aspx

Comment: Interesting article.  It does state that 32-bit and 64-bit worker processes can be run simultaneously in IIS7.  I have IIS7, and the Application Pools have always been set to True for Enable 32-bit Applications.  Unless I'm another step....

Comment: Are they currently running 32bit though?

Comment: In my first reply above, I asked if the IIS setting under Handler Mapping for ASPClassic executable file is supposed to be %windir%\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll - I'm wondering if that is significant since it points to 64-bit instead of 32-bit.  Anyway, following the article, I went to Task Manager, Processes and  I do not see either one of the IIS Worker Processes (w3wp.exe) listed.  I'm trying to figure out how to open applicationHost.config to check the aspnet_filters.

Comment: <isapiFilters>
<filter name="ASP.Net_4.0_64bit" path="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_filter.dll" enableCache="true" preCondition="runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" />
            <filter name="ASP.Net_4.0_32bit" path="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_filter.dll" enableCache="true" preCondition="runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" />
        </isapiFilters>

Comment: PART 1 (too long to add in one part)
<applicationPools>
            <add name="DefaultAppPool" autoStart="true" enable32BitAppOnWin64="true" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPipelineMode="Integrated" />
            <add name="ASP.NET v4.0" autoStart="true" enable32BitAppOnWin64="true" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" />

Comment: PART 2: 
            <add name="ASP.NET v4.0 Classic" autoStart="true" enable32BitAppOnWin64="true" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPipelineMode="Classic" />
            <applicationPoolDefaults enable32BitAppOnWin64="true" managedPipelineMode="Integrated">
                <processModel identityType="ApplicationPoolIdentity" loadUserProfile="true" setProfileEnvironment="false" />
            </applicationPoolDefaults>
        </applicationPools>

Comment: I have no worker processes running in IIS so will try to figure that out if I can.  I have never had to deal with this. Everything has run smoothly for years until this last crash.

Comment: This is a question for Server Fault. But it sounds like you need to call a professional in

Comment: I was thinking the same.  Or reinstall Windows.... :((

Comment: In April, I created a Windows repair disk.  I've never used one.  Would using that provide me a restore point for all my settings in April, possibly fixing this problem?  I know I'd have a lot of catch-up on updates, but still....better than having to reinstall all my work.

Comment: You don't have to reinstall anything, you already told me that you have the correct DSNs in the 32bit environment. You just have to set the web app to run 32bit! This is not a programming problem any more. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/325824/Running-a-bit-application-under-IIS-on-a-bit

Comment: Sorry for my inexperience, I am just a home user.  I've mentioned a couple times that my App Pools were already set to enable 32-bit (true), as shown in the config file.  Maybe I'm missing another step?  I'll keep researching, thank you.